# Python access to object as a function (not __call__)

Tags: python

I want to do the following: I have a container-class Container, it has 
attribute attr, which refers to another class OtherClass.

```
class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self, value): 
        self._value = value 

    def default(self): 
        retirn self._value 

    def another(self): 
        return self._value ** 2 

    def as_str(self): 
        return 'String: %s' % self._value

class Container: 
    def __init__(self, attr): 
        self.attr = OtherClass(attr)
```

I want to:

```
x = Container(2) 

x.attr # when accessing the attribute - return value from default method
2 
x.attr.another() # but also an attribute can be treated as an object 
4 
x.attr.as_str()
'String: 2'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't believe I wasted 20 mins on this. Just make sure `attr` is a class that has a callable method `another`. It can't be done with properties, proxies or metaclassing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need. Seems like an odd design to me

```
>>> class OtherClass(int):
...     def __init__(self, value): 
...         self._value = value 
...     def another(self): 
...         return self._value ** 2 
... 
>>> class Container: 
...     def __init__(self, attr): 
...         self.attr = OtherClass(attr)
... 
>>> x=Container(2)
>>> x.attr
2
>>> x.attr.another()
4
```

just-because-you-use-classes-doesn't-mean-it's-OO-ly gnibbler

Comment: This seems the only plausible solution, even though doing this is simply nasty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless `OtherClass` overrides `__int__()` and you then put it through `int()` to get the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

What is `attr` meant to be? You can't have it both ways; either it's the return value of some function or it's an instance of `OtherClass`.

How about making `OtherClass` inherit from `Integer`?

Comment: Returned values can be different types.

Comment: In which case why can't you call `x.attr.default()` when you want its value?

Comment: I want to give developers a simple API. If no method specific - return  the default value.

In any case, thanks for help.